# Is it legal to for a function declared "inline" to be recursive?

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, inline, language-lawyer

I was thinking a little bit about the C programming language and started to wonder how `inline` interacts with recursion. I made this test program to find out.

```
static inline void f(void) {
    f();
}

int main(void) {
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile the program using `gcc` and get no warnings at all

```
$ c99 -Wall -pedantic main.c -o a
```

My question is

> What does the C standards say about mixing `inline` with recursion?

To me it seems logical that it should not be allowed.

Comment: So what happened when you tried without `inline`? And why do you think  is it logical that it should not be allowed? It doesn't seem very logical to me.

Comment: `inline` IIRC is a hint, not a requirement. You're getting a segmentation fault because `f()` has no termination condition and thus recurses infinitely, blowing up your stack.

Comment: Yes, it is a stack overflow but my question remains: "Is it legal?"

Comment: Why would it not be legal?

Comment: The function cannot inline the body of itself in itself. Yes, I know. `inline` is just a "hint" and the compiler is free to ignore it but I still don't think that it makes sense to allow `inline` functions to be recursive. I just don't think it is logical.

Comment: @elias: Ok, so the answer is "yes, it is legal", because the standard says nothing to the contrary.

Comment: Even with recursion compiler is free to do an equivalent of loop unrolling and inline the function to a certain number of levels, after which it will call itself.

Comment: @elias: The only reliable effect of `inline` is to be more permissive with multiple definitions for functions with external linkage (for `static` functions, it's not more than a hint, every static function in a valid C program can be made `inline`). E.g. it's also valid to take the address (which contradicts inlining just like recursive calls do).

Comment: And BTW, why three downvotes?

Comment: @mafso because the question makes no sense? It has some code that crashes, and somehow ties that to inlining recursive functions being logically not allowed... I find the up-votes quite surprising.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I, too, used to think `inline` means inlining; which isn't that absurd to believe. Just like `register` prohibits taking the address, it wouldn't be too illogical to assume `inline` would be somewhat similar. FWIW, I don't understand the upvotes either (not a great and helpful question, after all).

Comment: @mafso That's fine. But there is an irrelevant "test case" that manages to completely confuse the issue.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That code snippet could probably be summarized in one sentence (and the whole question could be made shorter). That doesn't reach my "downvote threshold", but I see your point (and I believe, diversity in voting behaviour is a good thing in general). I was just a little surprised about the votes (IMO, this question is far from the crap that normally shows up in the C tag.)

Comment: I have now removed the invalid test case due to the confusion it led to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting the standard: (§6.7.4 **Function Specifiers**,  para. 6)

> A function declared with an inline function specifier is an inline function. Making a function an inline function suggests that calls to the function be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.

Oddly, nothing in that paragraph says anything about inlining inline functions; only that the calls should be fast.

It's possible for the compiler to decide to inline *some* of the calls to the function. For example, in a recursive inline function, the compiler may choose to inline the first `k` recursive calls, for some smallish value of `k`. (Of course, it might decide to do that anyway. Not declaring a function 'inline` doesn't prevent the compiler from inlining it.)